# Batch printing PDF files with laravel

Tags: laravel, pdf

I have a program that can print an individual PDF when on a students file. I'm doing this using niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf package in Laravel 5.7. It's working great because I can just stream the pdf from a view into the browser then print from there.

Now I'm wanting to batch print the PDF's at the end of the day instead of one by one. How can I do this? There's no documentation for this on the package repository.

Several ways I've thought of doing this: one, save each PDF as an image file then try to print all files in that folder at the end of the day. If I do this, how would I print all files in that folder?

Next: does anyone know a way to maybe append a new PDF to a variable containing all the previously looped pdf's?
For example:

```
$finalpdf;

$students = Student::all();
foreach($students as $student){
  $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.document', $student);

  $finalpdf .+ $pdf; //i know this line doesn't work, but how to alter it?

    return $pdf->save('document.pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a few days of playing around, hopefully this solution helps someone in the future. I used another package called "lara pdf merger". By writing my files to a save destination, adding those files to a merged file, then deleting the saved files after download, I was able to get my functionality. This is my controller code:

```
use PDF;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use LynX39\LaraPdfMerger\Facades\PdfMerger;


public function batchPrint(){
  $pdfMerger = PDFMerger::init();
  $i = 0;

  $students = Student::whereDate('updated_at', Carbon::today('America/Los_Angeles'))->get();
    foreach ($students as $student) {
      $pdf = PDF::loadView('printTables', compact('student'));
      $pdf->save('pdf/document'.$i.'.pdf');
      $pdfMerger->addPDF('pdf/document'.$i.'.pdf');
      $i++;
    }

  $pdfMerger->merge();
  $pdfMerger->save("file_name.pdf", "browser");

  $file = new Filesystem;
  $file->cleanDirectory('pdf');

}
```